# Java read text file string separated with space and store it

Tags: java

The sample text file.

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000000    111.221.77.175        10.1.1.12             TCP      60     40016
```

zfirm-shiprush3 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=83 Len=4

Frame 1: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: TechnoSc_12:16:d7 (00:e0:b4:12:16:d7), Dst: IntelCor_52:cb:ec (00:24:d7:52:cb:ec)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 111.221.77.175 (111.221.77.175), Dst: 10.1.1.12 (10.1.1.12)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 40016 (40016), Dst Port: zfirm-shiprush3 (3841), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 4
Data (4 bytes)

I only found out how to read the file character by character or read and print the file, but i can't use it. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to read this and make it usable.

Comment: Show the code you have tried

Comment: Format Text File Values

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scanner` and `File` object.

```
File file = new File("MY_FILE.TXT"); // Change this to your file name

try {
  Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
  while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    String word = fileReader.next(); 
    //Now you can use the word. By default, Scanner is space-delimited.
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Handle error...
}
```

If you need a more complex delimiter for your Scanner, replace the declaration line with `Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("[\t\r\n ]+");`, replacing the regular expression with one that fits your needs.